# ResolveDependencies returns null for a specific service with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, unity-container

I am having a web api application written in c#, and i have used app insights to log the exceptions, so i have registered a service as follows,

```
private IExceptionLogService ExceptionLogService { get; set; }
```

and this is register inside the unity config as well,

```
<register type="IExceptionLogService" mapTo="ExceptionLogService" />
```

but when i run the application, the configuration shows in debug as well, it shows the file and the assembly.

```
private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
{
            var section = (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity");
            var container = new UnityContainer().LoadConfiguration(section);
            return container;
}
```

but when i try to resolve the dependencies it returns null

```
private void ResolveDependencies(HttpConfiguration configuration)
{
    ExceptionLogService = ExceptionLogService ?? (IExceptionLogService)configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(IExceptionLogService));
}
```

what is the issue here?

Comment: Is there no any InneException behind `ExceptionLogService`.

Comment: No there is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You register dependency in Unity DI container that implements `IUnityContainer` interface but trying to resolve dependency through `HttpConfiguration.DependencyResolver` of `IDependencyResolver` type. By default `DependencyResolver` is set to instance of `System.Web.Http.Dependencies.EmptyResolver`. It's clear from `EmptyResolver` class name that it's just a stub that performs no actual resolving.

You should either provide your own implementation of `IDependencyResolver` that wraps `UnityContainer` or use some existing implementation. Sample implementation is described in article [Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection).

I suggest using of [Unity.WebAPI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.WebAPI/) NuGet package.

After you add this NuGet to your project, class `UnityConfig` will be added. Put your registrations to its `RegisterComponents()` method and add following call to `Application_Start()`:

UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();